# Keeping a datagrid in sync with a mysql database

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, data-binding

I'm experimenting with databinding in WPF

I have this datagrid that is bound to a mysql view, it's gonna be read only, but I'd like it to automatically refresh when changes are made to the database.
Couldn't find anything useful on google and I have no idea where to start.

This is the dataprovider class.

```
class ConDataProvider
{
    private MySqlDataAdapter adapter;
    private Data data;
    private DataTable table;

    public ConDataProvider(string query)
    {
        data = new Data();
        table = new DataTable("con_FullGrid");
        adapter = data.getAdapter(query);
        adapter.Fill(table);
    }
    public DataView GetDView()
    {
            dv = new DataView();
            dv.Table = table;
            return dv;
    }
}
```

And the XAML for the window

```
<Window x:Class="HelioWPF_Alpha01.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HelioWPF_Alpha01"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="676" Width="924" MinHeight="300" MinWidth="463" Background="{x:Null}">
<Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="ConDataProvider" ObjectType="{x:Type local:ConDataProvider}">
        <ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
            <sys:String>SELECT * FROM con_FullGrid</sys:String>
        </ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="btable" ObjectInstance="{StaticResource ConDataProvider}"
                        MethodName="GetDView"/>

</Window.Resources>
<Grid Name="mainGrid" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource btable}" KeyDown="mainGrid_KeyDown" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" >
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Name="dataGrid1" FrozenColumnCount="20" RowHeight="25" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" ColumnWidth="*" MouseDoubleClick="dataGrid1_MouseDoubleClick" SelectionMode="Single" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" TabIndex="1" GotKeyboardFocus="dataGrid1_GotKeyboardFocus">
        <DataGrid.AlternatingRowBackground>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0.5" StartPoint="0,0.5">
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0" />
                <GradientStop Color="#16436DF8" Offset="0" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </DataGrid.AlternatingRowBackground></DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

What I have been doing is kind of faking it by reinitializing the ConDataProvider class in behind code and rebinding the datagrid on various events.
But it's an ugly hack.
I wouldn't mind redesigning the whole thing if I have to.

The Data class just contains the connection string and some methods to interact with the database.
You can see it here: http://pastebin.com/m9HLfwEQ

Thanks in advance.
Hope to get some good tips.

Comment: Not sure about MySql but Microsoft SQL has Service Broker which has Notification Services..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about if you wire up some [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx).

What you could do is create an observable that polls your DB every X seconds.  Then have your Observer connect to that observable.  In the OnNext event of the Observer, you could add the data to your grid, or rebind, whatever.

Essentially, you'd be creating something that sits between your database and your app that listens for changes and pushes those changes to you.

Comment: Thanks I'll have to look into this. Noob question: could I make this run server side, just watching the database, then report back to the application if there's some new data instead of having the client constantly fetch from the database?

Comment: Server side as in DB Server? Not that I know of.  At least not natively.  You could write a service that sits on the same box and notifies your client app.   But it wouldn't be native to MySql.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL appends information in Log whenever data is changed in database. This feature might have to be turned on, not sure if it is on by default.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-log.html

With this, you can run a service on Server side that would listen for changes on MySQL tables and send an event to client if tables are updated.

Clients would need to implement code for refreshing the grid on receiving such events from server.

To scan bin logs for changes, bin-log utility can be used.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlbinlog.html

I would use this approach instead of scanning the table for data changes if amount of data or amount of transactions is high. Otherwise approach of polling the DB should work fine.